# How to create a a spark dataframe from Integer RDD

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

How can I create a `DataFrame` from an `JavaRDD` contains Integers. I have done something like below but not working.

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(101, 103, 105);
JavaRDD<Integer> inputRDD = sc.parallelize(input);
DataFrame dataframe = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(inputRDD, Integer.class);
```

I got `ClassCastException` saying `org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently (although not intuitively), this `createDataFrame` overload can only work for "Bean" types, which means types that **do not correspond to any built-in Spark SQL type**.

You can see that in the source code, the class you pass is matched with a Spark SQL type in [`JavaTypeInference.inferDataType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/JavaTypeInference.scala#L61), and the result is cast into a `StructType` (see `dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]` in [`SQLContext.getSchema`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L863) - but the built in "primitive" types (like `IntegerType`) are **NOT** `StructType`s... Looks like a bug or undocumented behavior to me....

**WORKAROUNDS**:

1. Wrap your `Integer`s with a "bean" class (that's ugly, I know):

   ```
   public static class MyBean {
       final int value;

       MyBean(int value) {
           this.value = value;
       }

       public int getValue() {
           return value;
       }
   }

   List<MyBean> input = Arrays.asList(new MyBean(101), new MyBean(103), new MyBean(105));
   JavaRDD<MyBean> inputRDD = sc.parallelize(input);
   DataFrame dataframe = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(inputRDD, MyBean.class);

   dataframe.show(); // this works...
   ```
2. Convert to `RDD<Row>` yourself:

   ```
   // convert to Rows:
   JavaRDD<Row> rowRdd = inputRDD.map(new Function<Integer, Row>() {
       @Override
       public Row call(Integer v1) throws Exception {
           return RowFactory.create(v1);
       }
   });

   // create schema (this looks nicer in Scala...):
   StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{new StructField("number", IntegerType$.MODULE$, false, Metadata.empty())});

   DataFrame dataframe = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema);
   dataframe.show(); // this works...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Now in Spark 2.2 you can do the following to create a Dataset.

```
Dataset<Integer> dataSet = sqlContext().createDataset(javardd.rdd(), Encoders.INT());
```